# Spring Boot @Query annotation throwing unexpected token error on the alias

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Below is the snippet of the offending code

```java
package com.example.demo.repositories;

import com.example.demo.models.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Student WHERE s.email = ?1")
    Optional<Student> findStudentByEmail(String email);
}
```

This a piece of the error returned

```
caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [s.email], unexpected token [s]...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed alias(in your case 's') with the entity name.

so it should be,

```
 @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.email = ?1")
 Optional<Student> findStudentByEmail(String email);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.email = ?1")
Optional<Student> findStudentByEmail(String email);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

- As already outlined in the other answers, you missed **declaring the alias** in the statement. Thus the correct code should be

  ```java
  @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.email = ?1")
  Optional<Student> findStudentByEmail(String email);
  ```
- Alternatively, if your query is simple as the one above, you can try **omitting the alias** as shown in the below example

  ```java
  @Query("FROM Student WHERE email = ?1")
  Optional<Student> findStudentByEmail(String email);
  ```